# Java How to increase the message size of a grpc server in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, grpc, grpc-java

I have a Spring Boot micro-service which listens through GRPC using [LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter)

By default GRPC payload maximum size is 4MB. At client side, it's easy to set the response payload size, but I want to increase the request size at the server side.

At client side,

```
ManagedChannel channel = 
   NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress(...)
                        .maxInboundMessageSize(NEW_MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE).build();
```

By server code:

```
@GRpcService
public class FooService extends FooServiceImplBase {

  @Override
  public void foo(GetRequest request, StreamObserver<GetResponse> responseObserver) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use streaming for this purpose instead of increasing the message size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a ServerBuilderConfigurer like this:

```
@Component
public class FooServerBuilderConfigurer extends GRpcServerBuilderConfigurer {
  public static final int NEW_MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE = 100 * 1024 * 1024; // 100MB

  @Override
  public void configure(ServerBuilder<?> serverBuilder) {
    serverBuilder.maxInboundMessageSize(NEW_MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE);
  }
}
```